# What is the correct alternative to resetting a mock after setup in Mockito?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I'm new to unit testing and trying to learn the proper style. I like to setup the object that I am testing so that I can test it as if it were in use instead of only testing a newly constructed object. I can't test removing things from an object that is empty, as many objects are when constructed.

Take the following for an example where ObservedList is being tested and ListListener is a necessary class that is being mocked.

```
public final class ObservedListTest {
  private ListListener<Integer> listener;
  private ObservedList<Integer> list;
  @BeforeMethod public void setup() {
    listener = mock(ListListener.class);
    list = new ObservedList<Integer>(listener);
    list.addAll(Arrays.asList(1,2,3));
    reset(listener);
  }
  @Test public void addFirst() {
    list.add(0, -1);
    verify(listener).listEdited(list, 0, 1, Collections.<Integer>emptyList());
    verifyNoMoreInteractions(listener);
  }
  @Test void addAtEnd() {
    list.add(9);
    verify(listener).listEdited(list, 3, 4, Collections.<Integer>emptyList());
    verifyNoMoreInteractions(listener);
  }
  @Test void removeMiddle() {
    list.remove(Integer.valueOf(2));
    verify(listener).listEdited(list, 1, 1, Collections.singletonList(2));
    verifyNoMoreInteractions(listener);
  }
}
```

As a novice this seems to work well to me, but I know that it's bad practice because it uses the `reset` method. I call `reset` because I don't want the actual tests to get confused due to interactions that happened in the setup.

The javadoc for `reset` doesn't even get around to telling you what the method does because it is so busy telling you that you shouldn't use it. Ordinarily I'd simply take that advice and avoid `reset` by removing my `setup` method and adjusting my tests to look more like this:

```
  @Test void removeMiddle() {
    listener = mock(ListListener.class);
    list = new ObservedList<Integer>(listener);
    list.addAll(Arrays.asList(1,2,3));
    list.remove(Integer.valueOf(2));
    InOrder inOrder = inOrder(listener);
    inOrder.verify(listener).listEdited(list, 0, 3,
      Collections.<Integer>emptyList());
    inOrder.verify(listener).listEdited(list, 1, 1,
      Collections.singletonList(2));
    verifyNoMoreInteractions(listener);
  }
```

This *also* seems to work well to me. The problem is that the documentation for the `reset` method says:

> Instead of reset() please consider writing simple, small and focused
>   test methods over lengthy, over-specified tests.

I respect that Mockito is designed to encourage good style in unit tests and I want to learn from it, but I'm having a hard time sorting out what message it is trying to send me. When I eliminate `reset` from my tests, my tests get *complex*, *longer* and *less focused*, so obviously I'm doing it wrong.

What does doing it right look like?

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `reset`. Remove the `verifyNoMoreInteractions`. Problem solved. Your tests are simpler, shorter, and more focused.

Comment: That would make my tests far more permissive. Isn't that declaring that ObservedList is allowed to send incorrect messages to ListListener? I don't want to allow that. If permissiveness were a good thing I could eliminate the test completely, permit everything, and that would be simplest of all, but I really would like to actually test this thing.

Comment: @Geo, Ryan is describing [the testing philosophy](http://monkeyisland.pl/2008/07/12/should-i-worry-about-the-unexpected/) that [Mockito was designed for](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#8), which favors flexible, loose tests over brittle, tightly-specified tests. Typically, unless you're testing listeners or callback behavior, extra method calls shouldn't cause a test to fail: By the time you expect and verify every call, you've duplicated the implementation inside-out within the test.

Comment: @JeffBowman, does this mean that Mockito shouldn't be used for mocking listeners or callbacks? It seems quite intent upon only being used for its own testing philosophy, but I hesitate to use a mix of multiple mocking tools.

Comment: @Geo, Mockito is fine for mocking callbacks and listeners--that's where you'd more likely see verifyZeroInteractions or verifyNoMoreInteractions, because method interactions (or lack thereof) are specifically a documented part of the API of the system under test. My point is that those methods should be rarely used outside of that.

Answer (score 2):

Mockito 2.1 added a `clearInvocations` method, which can be used like this:

```
public final class ObservedListTest {
  private ListListener<Integer> listener;
  private ObservedList<Integer> list;

  @BeforeMethod public void setup() {
    listener = mock(ListListener.class);
    list = new ObservedList<Integer>(listener);
    list.addAll(Arrays.asList(1,2,3));
    clearInvocations(listener);
  }

  @Test public void addFirst() {
    list.add(0, -1);
    verify(listener, only()).listEdited(list, 0, 1, Collections.<Integer>emptyList());
  }

  @Test void addAtEnd() {
    list.add(9);
    verify(listener, only()).listEdited(list, 3, 4, Collections.<Integer>emptyList());
  }

  @Test void removeMiddle() {
    list.remove(Integer.valueOf(2));
    verify(listener, only()).listEdited(list, 1, 1, Collections.singletonList(2));
  }
}
```

Note that `clearInvocations` javadoc also states:

> Try to avoid this method at all costs. Only clear invocations if you
>   are unable to efficiently test your program.